# Bitrise build fail "Failed to commit edit, error: googleapi: got HTTP response code 502 with body: <!DOCTYPE html>"

Tags: deployment, google-play, bitrise

Today my bitrise build fail at the step:

```
Committing edit
Failed to commit edit, error: googleapi: got HTTP response code 502 with body: <!DOCTYPE html>
```

[image]

I dont know if anyone having the same issue like me because yesterday it was working well, it seem the issue come from Google, plus I didn’t change anything since yesterday.

However, the build was successfully uploaded to the Google Play and run normally when I download it to my phone…that’s weird

Thanks and regards,

Viet

Answer (score 3):

The issue is tracked here https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-google-play-deploy/issues/108 and under investigation.

Comment: Oke, "cảm ơn ông" :D